# Reverse sort of Product Collection

Tags: product-collection

I have something like this

```
foreach ($this->getProductCollection()as $prod) { ?>
.....
```

And I want to reverse the foreach loop so that it starts with the last product in the array.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `addAttributeToSort()` method of the Product Collection object before using it in a loop.

Something like that:
    //Correcting Misspellig, it was attAttribute
    $this->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('attr_name', 'desc');
    foreach ($this->getProductCollection() as $prod) {
    ...
    }

[more about collections](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection::attAttributeToSort()

Comment: it is addAttributeToSort not attAttributeToSort.

Answer (score 0):

In place of **`addAttributeToSort`** you can also use **`setOrder('fieldname', direction [asc/desc])`**